# bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, oracle

When I open my terminal, I see this on top of the terminal.
I removed Oracle XE. However, I cannot remove this line from my terminal.
Also I cannot remove Oracle user from my group. What can I do?

> bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the installation has an /etc/profile.d file left behind, [possibly named](https://github.com/UKHomeOffice/docker-oracle-database-express-edition-11g/blob/master/entrypoint.sh) oracle-xe.sh or [20oos_oraclexe.sh](https://github.com/UKHomeOffice/docker-oracle-database-express-edition-11g/blob/master/entrypoint.sh). Find that file and remove it, e.g.:

```
rm /etc/profile.d/oracle-xe.sh
rm /etc/profile.d/20oos_oraclexe.sh
```

If the file has a different name, find it with:

```
egrep -l 'ORACLE_HOME|11.2.0/xe' /etc/profile.d/*.sh
```

According to the [Oracle® Database Express Edition Installation Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL125), an entry may have been added to your ~/.profile:

> echo '. /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh' >>./.profile

... in which case you'd want to remove that line from your .profile:

```
sed -i '/oracle\/product\/11.2.0\/xe/d' ~/.profile
```